# podman Exited status list

Tags: podman

could you please indicate to me if there is a list of all possibles "Exited status codes"
for Podman?

Often, containers exited with different exit codes and is difficult every time to search on the web the meaning of them. For example like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#exit-status

| exit code | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| 125 | The error is with Podman itself |
| 126 | The contained command cannot be invoked |
| 127 | The contained command cannot be found |
| Exit code | contained command exit code |

I guess this means that the exit status of Podman is normally the exit status of the command that was run in the container. The only exception to this is when the Podman exit status is 125, 126 or 127.